# SwiftUI onTapGesture cancels AttributedString link tap

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an `AttributedString` with a link in my UI like so:

struct ContentView: View {

```
private let attributedString: AttributedString = {
    var attributedString = AttributedString("Notifications disabled. Please enable them in Settings.")
    attributedString.foregroundColor = .black

    if let range = attributedString.range(of: "Settings") {
        attributedString[range].foregroundColor = .blue
        attributedString[range].link = .init(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)
    }

    return attributedString
}()

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.white
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Tapped")
            }

        Text(attributedString)
    }
}
```

For some reason the `onTapGesture` blocks the link tap gesture from happening. It's not really an option for me to move the tap gesture to the `ZStack` either as this will block a different gesture in my main app. How can I fix this?

Comment: maybe your `.init(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)` is not giving you the url you expect (i.e gives you a bad url).
 This works for me: `attributedString[range].link = URL(string: "https://apple.com")`

Comment: you can try Text(.init(attributedString))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Text(.init(text)) { word in
                    if let range = word.range(of: "click here.") {
                        word[range].underlineStyle = .single
                        word[range].link = URL(string: "https://aspas.notion.site/Cue-Placeholders-64a63f03a7794d00bdf3f077c4ff5723")
                    }
                }

extension Text {

init(_ string: String, configure: ((inout AttributedString) -> Void)) {
    var attributedString = AttributedString(string) /// create an `AttributedString`
    configure(&attributedString) /// configure using the closure
    self.init(attributedString) /// initialize a `Text`
} }
```